# Custom camera app failing to store big (size) images

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm trying to build camera app and [this](http://archive.oreilly.com/oreillyschool/courses/android2/CameraAdvanced.html) tutorial helped me very well but there is only one problem. Whenever I take a Pic which includes color and stuff the size is usually big and it doesnt store image and the app crashes but when i take pic of, for example, Black color (By putting my finger on camera), the app works perfectly fine.

I've checked my log and it states: "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION". Can anyone please check this tutorial and can explain why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    mCameraData = data;
   // there write data into file then convert inot bitmap.
  }

Comment: @Opriday can you please explain how do i write data into file then convert it into bitmap?

Comment: FileInputStream writePicture = new FileOutputStream(..File path....);
                        writePicture.write(data);
                        writePicture.close();......................For reading file and converting to bitmap follow these line.........
                        FileInputStream readPicture = new FileInputStream(pictureCreate);
                        BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(readPicture);
                       Bitmap  bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bf);
                        readPicture.close();